# Photo site in Ruby on Rails- How to upload photos via admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, photo-gallery

What is the best way to be able to upload photos to a portfolio on a website created in ruby on rails via the admin? I then need the photos to upload into a javascript library. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave). These two are good gems for photo-uploading. As per 'via admin' thing, that depends on your authentication system.

Comment: nice screencast for CarrierWave: http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads